# How to prevent React component from rendering if not logged in

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a React component that is rendered when I visit the `/service` path of my website. E.g. `my-site.com/service`.

The problem is, this page should only be viewable if logged in, otherwise, get redirected to the login page. However, before redirecting, the component gets flashed to the screen for a split second.

How can I prevent my component from showing at all when not yet logged in?

**This is how I have tried so far:**
I am using a `class component`.

In `componentDidMount()`, if the `getUsers` function returns an error (meaning not logged in), then set the `redirect` variable to `true`.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    UserService.getUsers().catch((err) => {
      this.setState({ redirect: true });
    });
  }
```

And then I use that variable like this:

```
 render() {
    const { redirect } = this.state;
    if (redirect) {
      return <Navigate to="/login" />;
    }

    return (
      <Fragment>
         <div>This is my div</div>
         <div>OTHER IMPORTANT DATA</div>
     <Fragment>
    );
  }
```

So when not logged in, you can still my `div` and `OTHER IMPORTANT DATA` for a split second before you get redirected. How can I prevent this from happening?

This is my `App.js`:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Router>
        <HeaderComponent />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}></Route>
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />}></Route>
          <Route path="/service" element={<MyComponent />}></Route>
          <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />}></Route>
        </Routes>
        <FooterComponent />
      </Router>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: did you use react-router for routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another state value indicating whether loading is finished or not. If its not loaded, render nothing (or a placeholder). If it is loaded, then do the same thing you're doing now.

```
state = {
  redirect: false,
  loaded: false,
}

componentDidMount() {
  UserService.getUsers()
    .then(() => {
      this.setState({ loaded: true }); 
    }).catch((err) => {
      this.setState({ loaded: true, redirect: true });
    });
}

render() {
  const { redirect, loaded } = this.state;
  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }
  if (redirect) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" />;
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
       <div>This is my div</div>
       <div>OTHER IMPORTANT DATA</div>
    <Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use use [`render func`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func) which will allow you to perform some logic before  rendering the component which must be render when visiting the route `/service` you can do that like this when you define the route

```
<Route path="/service" render={(routeProps) => {
    // here you can perform you checking before rendering the component 
    if(authenticated) {
        return <MyComponent />
    } else {
        return <Redirect to="/somewhere/else" />
    }
}}></Route>
```

With this logic you should already define some way to check if the user is logged in or not and store it the the state use to perform the authentication check. And you will not have to define any logic inside of that component to check if the user is authenticated as it will only be rendered when the user is authenticated